# Styling the ActionBar

Tags: android

Re this example from the Android developer blog
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html
It says that to style the tabs on the action bar, to use a style like this:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
</style>
```

It references a parent style of "android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView_TabView" - which my project is unable to locate. I'm building against v3.2, with a min sdk of platform 8 (v2.2). I'm using ActionBarSherlock.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the sample code incorrect? What style can I inherit from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong, or is the sample code incorrect?

The sample code was correct at the time and no longer is correct.

@Macarse has [a blog post](http://android-argentina.blogspot.com/2011/08/error-retrieving-parent-for-item.html) with the fix. Quoting Xav's comment on [the related issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18659):

> What is happening is that some styles, like WindowTitle are not public (you won't find them in android.R.style). You should not be extending non public resources. aapt used to let you do that but it was a bug which was fixed in platform-tools r6.

Comment: I dug further, and as I'm using ActionBarSherlock I inherited from style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView and all is well in the world again. Android seems like two platforms atm - I look forward to a day when it's less split.